# Is there a way to see which line of code was just executed in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I'm debugging an iOS app in Xcode, and I'm wondering is there any way to see which line of code I just ran? I'm trying to figure out where the code is that is responsible for making a menu slide open when I tap the menu key.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there's a debugger that shows you this. Set a breakpoint and step from there.

Comment: Slightly outdated, but still useful, is my discussion on how to use the debugger: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_the_xcode_debugger

Comment: How can I set a breakpoint when I don't know where the file/code is? That's the whole point of this question

Comment: You could set a _symbolic_ breakpoint. It is called when some method is called. Read the discussion I pointed you to. You need to have _some_ idea what is happening here; it doesn't happen all by itself - it's your code!

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint (tap on a line number in Xcode) and manually run the code line by line using Xcode's `Debug` menu. In your case you can set a breakpoint on the method that is executed when a button is pushed. If you do not know which method is called when you push the button, you could look at where the button is declared, which should have a `addTarget` method, or see what it is hooked up to in the Storyboard.

If you have a few places where you think the code is executed, you can use `NSLog()` statements and see what is being printed to the console at what time.